# Android Crash Reports using ACRA in service

Tags: android, crash-reports, acra

I want to use ACRA in my app for crash reporting. I have used it earlier in other app.
My app doesn't have nay activity and is just a service. I want to have crash reports for service.

How can I use ACRA for this?

Its init function expects a reference of application class as argument. I tried using application class in my app but it is not working. Also if I create application class, it shows my app' icon on phone, which I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having an application class should be possible even if you don't have any Activity. When a service is started the Application class is created beforehand.

Check that you declared correctly your application in the manifest `<application name=".MyApplication">`.

The icon in the launcher should not appear if you don't have an Activity declared with LAUNCHER and MAIN intent filters.

Comment: I don't have any launcher activity but still it is showing the app icon. I also thought the same way as you and tried creating application class and declaring it in manifest. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use TestPoke a crash report platform, the integration is just only one line of code, you can leverage of it, sending logs and handled exception, so you will have a more granular control of which you want to see in your online reports.

http://www.testpoke.com

Comment: It's not just one line of code. Looks to have similar if not greater integration hook requirements than ACRA. [https://testpoke.com/docs/overview](testpoke - Getting started)